# PackageNotFoundError: bokeh after compiling with pyinstaller

Tags: pyinstaller, bokeh, modulenotfounderror

I have a python project that imports bokeh, and I use pip install bokeh to install bokeh 3.0.3 version, and everything works fine. However, after I compile this project using pyinstaller, the executable file crashes at launch with the following error:

`importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: bokeh`

Also the way I'm importing bokeh functionalities into my project is like this:

`from bokeh.io import output_file, show`

I have searched around, but haven't been able to find any useful clue on how to solve this issue. I would appreciate any help on this.

Python versoin 3.8.13
Pyinstaller version: 5.7.0

I have also tried using conda to install bokeh, but it does not make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this issue useful for your case.

https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/discussions/6033

In your case there is the need to include the "--copy-metadata bokeh" command when you are running pyInstaller or use the copy_metadata() function in your spec file.

For more details refer to the github issue as it goes a little more in detail.